# How to check reference collection has matched data or not in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 2 simple collections as below.

1. Product

   - Id
   - name
   - description
2. likes

   - id
   - userId
   - productId

Now I want a boolean key if the user liked that product or not.

Expected output:

- _id
- name
- description
- hasLiked

I have tried by lookup but it's not working.

```
.lookup({
    from: 'likes',
    let: {
      productId: "$productId"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match:
        {
          $expr:
          {
            $and:
              [
                { $eq: ["$productId", "$$_id"] }
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "hasLiked"
  })
```

Comment: you use the lookup wrong syntax, the let refers to fields from the left collection, not the right one(the likes is the right one, products is the left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to fix your lookup,

- pass `_id` in `productId` key
- check `userId` condition, input your userId
- check the product id condition in the expression

```
.lookup({
    from: 'likes',
    let: { productId: "$_id" },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                userId: "" // input your userId
                $expr: { $eq: ["$$productId", "$productId"] },
            }
        }
    ],
    as: "hasLiked"
})
```

Need to check condition in stage,

- `$ne` to check `hasLiked` is not equal to `[]` then true otherwise false

```
.addFields({
    hasLiked: { $ne: ["$hasLiked", []] }
})
```